# How to pass string as command line arguments while using R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, string, command-line-arguments

While using R CMD BATCH in Linux terminal to run my R program, I want to pass a string as command line argument. For example, I want to pass `mydir="/home/test"` as a command line argument.

I ever tried: `R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args a=0 mydir="/home/test"' test.R`, but I failed.

Sincerely thank anybody who can provide me with some help!

Comment: What does your R code look like. Etc do you have an args=commandArgs() section? See <https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/>

Comment: @MDEWITT I have solved this issue by myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args a=0 mydir="/home/test"' test.R` works.
Remember add `args <- commandArgs(trailingonly=TRUE)` to the program at the beginning. That's why my program reported an error, I forgot to add it to my program.